# How to prevent Delphi MainForm to show when a file dialog is showing?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, mainwindow

My application has many forms, there is also one more important form, that is the main form, the behaviour is in general ok but in same cases (for example when I open a file dialog from a subform) the beahviour is: subform is hidden and mainform is shown.

How to avoid this?

Comment: This should not happen. You need to give us some code.

Comment: Ok, I'll see. I will to a sample and then as it is ready I will post again.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you either implicitly or explicitly set the `PopupParent` of both the sub-form and the dialog. If you open both the sub-form and the dialog from some random bit of code somewhere and don't tell Windows about the correct Z-order, stacking issues can happen.